# How to access reference data field in firestore using Angularfire2?

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

[This is my Tasks Collection where assignee field refers to users collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GvRB.png)

[This is the output i am getting when i fetch tasks collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDXL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//SAVING...
let ref = db.collection('nameOfCollection').doc('documentId').ref
     //Focus ".ref" at the end
db.collection('otherCollection').doc('otherDocumentId').set({ nameRef:ref })


//READING...
db.collection('otherCollection').doc('otherDocumentId').ref.get().then(res=>{
   //this "res.data().nameRef" 
   //it is the same as  
   //"db.collection('nameOfCollection').doc('documentId').ref"
})
```

I do not know if I could help but I did what I could unfortunately.
I still do not know how to speak English, sorry.